# Sharepoint List Lookup Column not showing titles correctly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I've got a list with 34 items in which is used as a lookup column in other lists.

For some reason in the other lists it does not bring over the title correctly. There are 34 rows but some of the titles are duplicating for some reason.

Here's some images to illustrate the problem.

[image: Actual List] - the actual list as it should be
[image: List shown in Infopath] - the list as Lookup in InfoPath Form
[image: List shown in Edit mode in other list] - the list as lookup in Sharepoint Edit Mode

Any Ideas? I've tried adding a new lookup column pointing to the list and it still does the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can see a possible solution for you here. Visit https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85063/why-are-duplicate-list-items-being-created-when-i-submit-an-infopath-form-to-my

Comment: Hi thanks for the info but that is a different problem as they are getting duplicate entries on submit where as I'm getting duplicate entries on display from a lookup list in which the list itself is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the lookup list from scratch and added the new column to the secondary list and seems to be fine now. Not sure what was wrong with the original list.